# Is it possible to drag and swap rows between two gridviews, if so how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, row

I want to swap rows between gridviews by dragging one row from gridview1 to dropping it on the row that I want to swap it with on gridview2, consequently it should update the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) or [Datatables](http://datatables.net/), or [this](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) example.

Comment: While both recommendations are nice, none of them will provide this functionality out of the box. There are no easy hooks to allow drag and drop of rows and invoke a callback function to update the DB. It's possible to do, but requires quite a bit of code.

Comment: Another example [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2010/02/24/drag-and-drop-table-rows-between-tables-with-jquery-ui.aspx).

Comment: That link is useful, indeed, but has nothing to do with DataTables or jQGrid specifically.